# How do I change labels of the enumerate environment?

Tags: formatting, enumerate

I write

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item MMMMMM
\item NNNNNNN
\end{enumerate}
```

but when I compiled appear:

```
a)MMMMMMM
b)NNNNNNNN
```

I wish the item to appear in Arabic numerals instead of letters

```
1)MMMMMMM
2)NNNNNNN
```

Comment: You have been here a while and still your posts are a mess. Sorry, I needed to write this! And the default setup isn't `a)` etc. It's `1.` etc.

Comment: I've changed the title of your question to a more suitable one. If you don't like it, revert it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The standard setup of `enumerate` does not use `a)` labelling -- it's `1.` etc.

There are basically three possibilities to do achieve the `1)` style:

- Reformat the counter output for the label
- Use `enumitem` package and its `label=...` option to the environment
- Use `enumerate` package and say `\begin{enumerate}[1)]....`

---

A `enumitem` quick and dirty solution ....

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item This
\item is
\item the
\item traditional 
\item labelling
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}[label={\arabic*)}]
\item This 
\item is 
\item another
\item way
\item of 
\item labelling
\end{enumerate}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Basically the same can be achieved with (watch the different label separations/indentations!) `enumerate` package:

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{enumerate}

\begin{document}


\begin{enumerate}
\item This
\item is
\item the
\item traditional 
\item labelling
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}[1)]
\item This 
\item is 
\item another
\item way
\item of 
\item labelling
\end{enumerate}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To change `enumerate` and other similar environments label style globally, the `enumitem` package also has a `setlist` command, which can be applied to all levels or a specific level:

```
% \setlist[environment,<levels>]{<options>}
\setlist[enumerate]{label=\arabic*)}  % all levels
\setlist[enumerate,2]{label=\alph*)}  % level 2 only
```